# How can you increase Picasso disk caching size without OkHttp?

Tags: android, picasso

I want to increment disk cache size for Picasso but I cant use OkHttpDownlader because I am running out of methods (multi dex is not a solution right now).

I would like to know if it is possible to do. I could not find an example.

Another question is: Where I should put this code? In application class?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Picasso.Builder](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/) to  build your Picasso instance, and provide it with an Cache using the `memoryCache(Cache cache)` method.  Picasso provides an [LruCache](http://square.github.io/picasso/javadoc/) that you can create using your own predefined max size.

As for where you should put this code, thats up to you.  One option would be to write a static singleton to encapsulate most of the setup that you initialize in your application class, yes.

Comment: Thanks for the aswer but I am trying to increment Disk cache. Memory cache is not problem.

Comment: Not sure Picasso has a Disk based cache other than what your HTTP cache provides by default.

Comment: Thanks, but I could not found which HTTP cache uses Picasso by default .

Comment: hay @Submersed  i'am using picasso to load images from disk as follow picasso.with(context).load(file).into(imageview); ...... how can i set memory cash this way? thanx in advance